# Ubuntu 22.04 External Monitor getting no input from laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, monitor

I have recently upgraded to 22.04 from a broken 20.04 on my laptop(dual-boot).
It worked fine initially for about a week before the problems started.

Initially the built-in screen was not recognized by the OS, therefore I figured the problem was graphics.
I have a HP Victus 16-e0007ni with a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobi and build-in AMD Graphics. Here is a result of a command that might help.

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5)
```

I then swapped from what was described in the *Software & Update* application as a *custom installed driver*. To proprietary NVIDIA drivers using

```
~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 
~$ reboot
```

and similar commands (i.e. 470 et cetera), after testing all of them the same thing happened.

They fixed the problem of the laptop's built-in display not being recognized, however none of them recognized my external monitor.
Further, I tried the X.org drivers. Here it worked the first time I booted, however from then on I had to boot to safe mode first for it to boot in at all. So in conclusion I now switched back, using

```
~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

to nvidia-driver-515.

Anyway so here are a few suspicious things:

nvidia-smi throws this error. This leaves me to believe there is a error with loading the graphics driver.

```
~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

This is my GPU-Manager log file

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-515srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-515
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-510srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-510
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-470srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-470
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-450srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-418srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-390
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? no
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? yes
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 1002:1638
BusID "PCI:6@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:25a0
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Chassis type: "10"
Laptop detected
/etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override found. Will try runtimepm if the kernel supports it.
Linux 5.15 detected.
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x25a0"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Error while opening /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x25a0"? no
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? yes
Has intel? no
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Loading nvidia with "no" parameters
Has the system changed? No
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
(#######################################################################################)
...
//There is like 100 lines of this error
... 
(#######################################################################################) 
    can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
    can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file
    Takes 10000ms to wait for nvidia udev rules completed.
    AMD IGP detected
    NVIDIA hybrid system
    can't open /sys/module/nvidia/version
    Creating /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-offload.conf
    Removing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf
    Setting power control to "auto" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control
    Trying to create new file: /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
    Loading nvidia with "no" parameters
```

I think the sheer amount of Drivers installed may cause some future conflict.

```
~$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-515:amd64                   515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-515                       515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-470:amd64                470.129.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-515:amd64                515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-515:i386                 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-515:amd64                 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-515:i386                  515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64               1:1.1.9-1.1                             amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-encode-515:amd64                 515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-515:i386                  515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-515:amd64                  515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-515:amd64                   515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-515:amd64                     515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-515:i386                      515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
rc  linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.15.0-41-generic 5.15.0-41.44+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-41
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-515-5.15.0-41-generic 5.15.0-41.44+1                          amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-41 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-41-generic  5.15.0-41.44+1                          amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-41-generic
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-470                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-510                   510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-515                   515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-470                            470.129.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-510                            510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-515                            515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-515                          515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-470                   470.129.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-510                   510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-515                   515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-515                   515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-515                           515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                  all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515              515.48.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.2              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: This problem seems to have been solved with a recent update to NVIDIA 515 drivers.

Comment: Futher update: performance is also on par with a GLMark-2 score of 3600 and some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ubuntu 22.04 and the same thing happened to me when updated nvidia driver from 480 to recommended 515 one (there was no signal to the external monitor).

Upgrading kernel to 5.19 (instead of current 5.15) solved the problem for me.

To update kernel (mostly copy pasted from [kernel update](https://nextgentips.com/2022/04/26/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-to-5-18-release-on-ubuntu-22-04/))

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.3-051903-generic_5.19.3-051903.202208211442_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19.3/amd64/linux-headers-5.19.3-051903_5.19.3-051903.202208211442_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19.3/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.19.3-051903-generic_5.19.3-051903.202208211442_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.19.3/amd64/linux-modules-5.19.3-051903-generic_5.19.3-051903.202208211442_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo reboot -n
```

**ADDITIONALLY** I had to sign the kernel because had windows dual boot with secure boot, and the kernels in the repo were **NOT** signed. Did follow instructions from here [sign kernel](https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html)
(here in the last step there was a bash command to remove unsigned kernels which I did not understand. To be on the safe side I used the normal `rm` command instead).

Terveisin, Markus